# android - bitmap as a background in item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

I load bitmap and then set it as a background to an item in the adapter of my ListView this way:

```
currentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), sImgArray[position]));
```

Bitmaps are loaded into array from server before. And everything is okay on APIs before 20 or 21, but when higher, bitmaps are not shown. How to fix it?

I also tried this code of Picasso hoping it would solve my problem, but it didn't either. And I don't like it 'cause I need bitmaps to be shown simultaneously.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(URL)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                @TargetApi(16)
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        currentView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
                    } else {
                        currentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), bitmap));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this way ?

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Width_of_currentView,  Height_of_currentView, false);
      currentView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
     } else {
      Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Width_of_currentView,  Height_of_currentView, false);
      currentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), resizedBitmap));
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm having some problems with Width_of_currentView and Height_of_currentView. I used currentView.getWidth and currentView.getHeight() but something went wrong and the logs say they should be >0. So how to get Width_of_currentView and Height_of_currentView?

Comment: @JustinMcGuire, you can get width and height by int height=yourView.getLayoutParams().height;
int width=yourView.getLayoutParams().width;

Comment: Unfortunately, the same grey background on my emulator :(

Comment: @JustinMcGuire, what I did, I have scaled your bitmap as per your view's height and width so in this case bitmap is major concern, can u please double check with your main bitmap ?

Comment: I used the code you posted, got width and height with currentView.getLayoutParams().width/height (actually, something went wrong with the pics), but on my Nexus 5 emulator everything is the same